# How to get DB2 MQT last refresh time

Tags: sql, db2

For a DB2 on z/OS Materialized Query Table, how can you retrieve the last refresh time?

[The documentation states](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_refreshsystemmaintmqt.dita?lang=en) that one of the actions that DB2 takes during a REFRESH is to populate the catalog with a refresh timestamp.

> 4. Updates the DB2 catalog with a refresh timestamp and the cardinality
>      of the materialized query table

What catalog table and column holds this information?

I was looking for this in order to compare the time stamp with another resource to see if it has changed since the last refresh.  If the other resource has changed since the last refresh, the MQT must be refreshed.

Comment: It's so nice to so a self-answered question actually written properly, have an upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the last refresh timestamp in the **REFRESH_TIME** column on the table **SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS**

You could use the following SQL to retrieve the last refresh timestamp for a specific table:

```
SELECT REFRESH_TIME
FROM SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS
WHERE NAME = ?
AND CREATOR = ?
AND TYPE = 'M'
```

See the [IBM documentation for the SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysviewstable.dita?cp=SSEPEK_11.0.0%2F10-0-131&lang=en) table for more information.