# DB2 tablespace state last changetime

Tags: sql, db2, tablespace

Is there any db2 command or SQL query will show me last change time of table space to current state?

Comment: See if this helps... not sure... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122543/how-to-get-db2-mqt-last-refresh-time?rq=1

Comment: Which Db2 version/platform?

Comment: change of what -- the data in the space or the space definition?

Comment: also a tablespace can be partitioned so I'm not sure this question is answerable.

Comment: fairly sure you have to look at the filesystem

Comment: My question if fairly simple. LIST TABLESPACES SHOW DETAIL command shows me state of tablespaces, but I want to know how long they are in these state? When last change happened

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in tracking when a field changes in a table (any table but in your case the state field of the tablespaces system table) in DB2 LUW you can do this using CCD replication.  This will create a table with a row level audit of all changes to a table.

Details: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.repl.qrepl.doc/topics/iiyrqsubcccdtgts.html

---

Another option is to add a trigger to the table to update an external table with the timestamp data you need.

---

If you are interested in tracking when anything changes in a tablespace in LUW from the shell you can use

```
db2look -d <dbname> -l
```

To find out the tablespace details.  Look for lines like

```
USING (FILE '<file and path>' ...
```

Then you can look at the file system at that location to see when it was last changed.

Comment: Well, you could do that on Windows too, but the file modification timestamp is not at all correlated to the tablespace [_state_](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0060111.html).

Comment: @mustaccio -- I see your point, I was thinking state was not being used to refer to the specific field but the state of the files.  I'll leave the answer despite the downvote on the possibility this is helpful to the OP.

Comment: No, not really. _Tablespace state_ has specific meaning, nothing in your answer seems to address it. And replication?

Comment: @mustaccio -- yes the state is a field in the tablespace system meta table..  If you CCD replication on that table then you will have an audit of the time stamp when the field changes.